# (How to) When hovering over a logo, transforms up and text appears underneath?

Tags: html, css, animation, graphical-logo

On my website, I want to be able to hover my mouse over a logo, the logo will slide (or transform) up, and text will appear underneath. Once you move the mouse away, the logo will slide back down and the text disappears.

I am very new to CSS and HTML and have been self teaching myself.

Please help me out!

Comment: put your code attemps. to try to help you,

Comment: yo can find alot of samples if google your question. like this. https://www.joomla-monster.com/blog/web-development/css3-powered-hover-effects-for-your-logo

Comment: try an attemp if you stuck. share code a we will try help.

Comment: Use google to search you will get many answers. You just need to stop being lazy.

Comment: @Sand My apologies, I am very new to this and was unsure how to approach it with Google, most results are similar to what I was seeking but not exact. I am still learning much of the technical language.

Comment: Well SO is not place where people will provide you with exact codes so you can copy paste. As @JesusCarrasco and many others have asked in SO we try to help out to solve a problem only if the person who asked for help can't get it solved or basically we help people to trouble shoot their own code or help to improve the existing code with another function which the first person didn't know. You need to turn those not exact codes to what you want that's how you learn coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a demo that took a couple minutes to whip up. The animations are accomplished using CSS `transition`. Let me know if you have any questions.

```css
.logo {
  width: 180px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.logo__image {
  width: 100%;
  transition: transform .5s;
}

.logo__text {
  color: darkorange;
  font-size: .9em;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.logo:hover .logo__image {
  transform: translateY(-20px);
}

.logo:hover .logo__text {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
  <img class="logo__image" src="https://i.imgur.com/l2DkgFN.png" />
  <span class="logo__text">Home of the Whopper</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

This should get you started:

```css
/* The wrapper class that will contain the logo and the text */
.logo_wrapper {
  height: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* The logo will be the same height as the wrapper and transition for 300ms */
.logo_wrapper img {
  height: 40px;
  width: auto;
  transition: transform 300ms;
}

/* The text should also transition for 300ms */
.logo_wrapper .logo_text {
  transition: transform 300ms;
}

/* When hovering over the wrapper, the logo and text will "translate" up 40px */
.logo_wrapper:hover img, .logo_wrapper:hover .logo_text {
  transform: translateY(-40px);
}
```

```html
<div class="logo_wrapper">
  <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.png" alt="Stack Overflow" />
  <div class="logo_text">Stack Overflow</div>
</div>
```